# Get values from data frame in a new variable considering row and column index saved in another data frame

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a little problem with two dataframes in R. My dataframes has the next structure (I add `dput()` version in the final part). The first dataframe is `DF`:

```
   x1 x2 Index1 Index2
1 001  T      1      2
2 002  V      3      1
3 003  C      1      4
4 004  D      4      1
5 005  M      6      1
6 006  N      7      3
```

And the second dataframe is `DF2`:

```
   a1  a2 a3 a4
1 0.1 1.0 10  5
2 0.2 0.9  9  4
3 0.3 0.8  8  3
4 0.4 0.7  7  2
5 0.5 0.6  6  1
6 0.6 0.5  5  0
7 0.7 0.4  4  6
```

I am trying to solve this situation. In `DF` I have two columns `Index1` and `Index2`. In these columns I have values that I want to locate in `DF2` and save in a new variable for `DF` for example in the case of first row in `DF` I have in `Index1` a value of 1 and in `Index2` a value of 2, so when I use these values like index in brackets over `DF2` I got this:

```
DF2[1,2]
[1] 1
DF2[3,1]
[1] 0.3
DF2[1,4]
[1] 5
DF2[4,1]
[1] 0.4
DF2[6,1]
[1] 0.6
DF2[7,3]
[1] 4
```

That works fine but when I try to create a new variable to get these values I used a similar structure with brackets, so I used:

```
DF$I3=DF2[DF$"Index1",DF$"Index2"]
```

But I got this wrong result:

```
   x1 x2 Index1 Index2 I3.a2 I3.a1 I3.a4 I3.a1.1 I3.a1.2 I3.a3
1 001  T      1      2   1.0   0.1     5     0.1     0.1    10
2 002  V      3      1   0.8   0.3     3     0.3     0.3     8
3 003  C      1      4   1.0   0.1     5     0.1     0.1    10
4 004  D      4      1   0.7   0.4     2     0.4     0.4     7
5 005  M      6      1   0.5   0.6     0     0.6     0.6     5
6 006  N      7      3   0.4   0.7     6     0.7     0.7     4
```

Also I have tried with with `apply` with this structure:

```
DF$I3=apply(DF,1,function(x) DF2[x$"Index1",x$"Index2"])
```

But I got this mistake:

```
Error in x$Index2 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I would like to get a dataframe `DF` like this:

```
   x1 x2 Index1 Index2  I3
1 001  T      1      2 1.0
2 002  V      3      1 0.3
3 003  C      1      4 5.0
4 004  D      4      1 0.4
5 005  M      6      1 0.6
6 006  N      7      3 4.0
```

Where each value of `I3` is looked for in `DF2` according the values of `Index1` and `Index2`. The `dput()` version of `DF` and `DF2` are the next:

```
DF=structure(list(x1 = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006"
), x2 = c("T", "V", "C", "D", "M", "N"), Index1 = c(1, 3, 1, 
4, 6, 7), Index2 = c(2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3), I3 = c(1, 0.3, 5, 0.4, 
0.6, 4)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "Index1", "Index2", "I3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

DF2=structure(list(a1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7), a2 = c(1, 
0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4), a3 = c(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4), 
    a4 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6)), .Names = c("a1", "a2", "a3", 
"a4"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: +1 for providing your data as a `structure(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can index with a `matrix` object like this:

```
DF2[as.matrix(DF[c("Index1","Index2")])]
#[1] 1.0 0.3 5.0 0.4 0.6 4.0
```

Simplified example:

```
dat <- data.frame(one=1:5,two=6:10)
dat

#  one two
#1   1   6
#2   2   7
#3   3   8
#4   4   9
#5   5  10

mat <- cbind(c(1,3,5),c(1,2,1))
mat

#      row  col
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    3    2
#[3,]    5    1

dat[mat]
#[1] 1 8 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's useful to know why something didn't work. In that spirit,

```
DF$I3=apply(DF,1,function(x) DF2[x$"Index1",x$"Index2"])
```

has a couple of problems.

First, `apply(...)` coerces the first argument to a matrix, which by definition must have all cells of the same data type. Since the first two columns of `DF` are character, `DF` will be coerced to all character and, e.g., `DF$Index1` will be `c("1","3","1",...)`, which is not useful. You can solve that problem by passing just the relevant columns of `DF` to `apply(...)`. This will be coerced to a matrix of all numeric, which is what you want.

Second, `apply(DF,1,function(x){...})` passes the rows of `DF` as "atomic vectors", meaning you can reference them as, e.g. `x[1]`, or `x["Index1"]` but not `x$Index1`.

Putting this all together, any of these expressions

```
apply(DF[c("Index1","Index2")],1,function(x)DF2[x["Index1"],x["Index2"]])
# [1] 1.0 0.3 5.0 0.4 0.6 4.0

apply(DF[c("Index1","Index2")],1,function(x)DF2[x[1],x[2]])
# [1] 1.0 0.3 5.0 0.4 0.6 4.0

apply(DF[3:4],1,function(x)DF2[x[1],x[2]])
# [1] 1.0 0.3 5.0 0.4 0.6 4.0
```

yields the desired result.

Your first try,

```
DF$I3=DF2[DF$"Index1",DF$"Index2"]
```

extracts *all rows* corresponding to `DF$Index1` and *all columns* corresponding to `DF$Index2`.

Having said all this, the best way to do this is in the other answer: use matrix indexing.

Comment: Nice answer. Giving some background knowledge as to how the original tactics could work is always helpful.